# Not able to click under div element

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, particles.js

Hi there is a javascript named particles.js in [this](http://aliensix.com/particles-1.4/HTML/index-default-particles.html) bootstrap template. It works fine but as you can see, particles becomes unclickable under text section. Is there any way to make it clickable?

Here is the example:
https://bootdey.com/snippets/view/Particles-js-banner#preview

Comment: Particles are supposed to be background animation. And that what they do on this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick CSS solution would be to give `pointer-events: none` to your text elements. After inspecting your code this should be added to `.container`s.  This would make all pointer events like clicking ignore your text and go straight down to the backgrounds - although this disables selection of text.

To work around that you might have to use javascript solution like mapping `mousedown` events to the background element.